# ImageView animate

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have a problem with an animation. I wrote this code, but nothing happens.

```
public void animate(View v){
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByid(R.id.imageview);
    img.animate().translationYBy(-1000f).setDuration(300);
}
```

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this it may be help to you

```
public void SlideToY() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            -5.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

    slide.setDuration(2000);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    img.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for imageview animation. below example translate 150 pixel on right direction(x cordinate)

```
 Animation anim= new TranslateAnimation(xCurrentPos, xCurrentPos+150, yCurrentPos, yCurrentPos); 
anim.setDuration(1000); 
anim.setFillAfter(true); 
anim.setFillEnabled(true); 
animSurprise2Movement.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        xCurrentPos -= 150;
    }
});
imageview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm) to learn about android view animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this animation

```
public void animate(View v){
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByid(R.id.imageview);

        Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(4000);

        img.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all, now is working with my code. In think I have error in .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `start()` method.

```
public void animate(View v){
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByid(R.id.imageview);
    img.animate().translationYBy(-1000f).setDuration(300).start();
}
```